# AngularJs share $scope between controller and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I can't understand why I can't access to $scope properties from the directive, the documentation says that directives doesn't create new scopes, so why can't I acess the $scope properties?

**at app.js**

```
'use strict';

var climbingApp = angular.module('climbingApp', []);

climbingApp.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.initLocation = {
        lat: -54.798112,
        lng: -68.303375
    };
```

**at google-map.js**

```
'use strict';

climbingApp.directive('gmap', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div id="map-canvas"></div>',
            link: function(scope, iElement, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.initLocation);
            },
        }

    })
```

**at index.html**

```
  <html ng-app="climbingApp">
     <body>
    <gmap></gmap>

    </body>
    </html>

<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/dependencies/google-maps.js"></script>
```

The `console.log` always returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to associate the controller with the view (if you use `ngRoute`) or an element using `ng-controller`.  Something like this:

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl">...</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the scope into the controller

```
climbingApp.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the $scope in your controller like that :

```
var climbingApp = angular.module('climbingApp', ['ngRoute']);


    climbingApp.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.initLocation = {
            lat: -54.798112,
            lng: -68.303375
        };

        $scope.markers = [
            {
                'title' : 'prueba',
                'position' : [-54.798112, -68.303375] 
            },
            {   
                'title': 'prueba', 
                'position': [-54.798212, -68.303375] 
            }
        ];
    });


    'use strict';

    climbingApp.directive('gmap', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                template: '<div id="map-canvas"></div>',
                link: function(scope, iElement, attrs) {
                    console.log(scope.initLocation);
                },
            }

        })
```

working plunkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/fiK5viToLOVGobnAKZtB?p=preview

The log appears.

$scope or $location have to be pass in the function of your controller as param.

Comment: Because if you see your controller in the callback function you have no params. But in your controller you're using $scope. And in AngularJS if you want to use the $scope you have to pass it in param of the controller function. Do you understand it ?

Comment: Yeah, of course, I've injected the $scope into the 'ctrl' controller and it didn't work

Comment: If you have done it correct your post so because in your post is missing and post your real code too ! I'll help you

Comment: I've edited the post, that is the code that I've have now and it return me undefined on scope.initLocation but it return me an object on scope

Comment: Can you post the html and the router too please ?

Comment: I've deleted the router.